# Why doesn't my avatar/profile pic show on my activity?

Tags: support

See my answer here https://superuser.com/a/1091983/30982

It used to show up and stopped showing at some point.

https://superuser.com/users/30982/elijah-lynn

update: Adding screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Does re-uploading your image on Gravatar fix the problem?

Comment: It's there now (i.e., I can see it).  Glitches happen.

Comment: Hrm, I still don't see it.

Comment: I've had this problem before - apparently it's a gravatar glitch. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289979/why-are-my-questions-and-answers-showing-identicons-instead-of-my-profile-pic

Comment: Thanks, it was Gravatar. I updated it and then ctrl + shift + r the browser to force a browser cache refresh and it is showing now.

Comment: I sometimes see "holes" in the gravatar lists on the review page or chat rooms, and the community bot gravatar sometimes appears as an empty box on the main page.  It could be that some of this is related to the browser or add-ons.